# Angular: Type 'LatLng' is not assignable to type 'LatLngLiteral'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

Quizás alguien me pueda ayudar diciendome porque sucede lo siguiente:

Quiero calcular una distancia usando el método `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` de la api de google maps. Este recibe dos paramtros, que son las dos rutas que quiero calcular:

La primera se la pasa en cod

```
let gps2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-87.201458, 14.1060239);
```

La segunda ruta es tomada de la posición en el marcador del mapa se encuentre

```
var position: LatLng = {
        lat: this.selectedMarker.lat(),
        lng: this.selectedMarker.lng()
      }
this.bookingService.bookingModel.latlng = position;
```

Y para calcular la distancia solamente:

```
let gps2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-87.201458, 14.1060239);
let distanceinMetro = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(gps2, 
this.bookingService.bookingModel.latlng);
```

Pero en "this.bookinService.bookingModel.latlng" recibo el error:

```
(property) BookingService.bookingModel: BookingModel
Argument of type 'LatLng' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LatLng | LatLngLiteral'.
  Type 'LatLng' is not assignable to type 'LatLngLiteral'.
    Types of property 'lat' are incompatible.
      Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

Cabe destacar que el objeto position de type LatLng se almace en un servicio (localstorage) que es `this.bookingService.bookingModel.latlng` y este a su vez es un objeto de en donde se le pasa la Lat/Long type number.

¿Alguien sabe porque sucede esto? Entiendo que es porque uno tiene un type y el otro no, pero ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Puede servirte estudiar la documentación de Typescript al respecto https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: Mil gracias! Me pondré en para encontrar la sol. Gracias, nuevamente.